# How to get the Source website url on second website page load when i click on a button and it is redirected to another site.

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

As i am new to web application and I have an link on a website (say on ABC.com) when a user click on this link it is redirected to another website (say XYZ.com).

I want to find the Url of ABC.com on the Page Load of Xyz.com.

How we can find it also in the case of when the websites is running on the localhost too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```